# Angular: dynamically create componet from route url

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components, material-dialog

I am using Angular 6 in my application.
After calling a Web Api I compose an Angular route Url, for example `/module-name/component-name/par1Value/par2Value/par3Value`.

I now want to show the component from the read route in a Material Dialog.

How can I accomplish it?
Can I create the component from the Url, so that I can pass it to ***open*** method?

```
this.dialog.open(myCreatedComponent,
          {
            width: '900px',
            height: '600px'
          });
```

Or is there another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is: Why do you want it as dynamic component? What exactly is your goal? Does the normal router-outlet not fit for you?

Comment: Because the Web Api will return different angular route that I want to show dinamically.

Comment: As long as you know which component to render for each possible route that is returned from the web api, and you have those routes setup, I would use the `Router` service by injecting it into the code where you are handling the http call and once you have the url, use `this.router.navigate([path]);`

But I noticed that you are trying to open it in a dialog.  This can be more difficult, but essentially you would want to map the possible paths you get back from the web api to the components you want to render.